# After clicking on a computer in network, it says "This folder is empty"

Tags: networking, windows-10

Using Windows 10, after clicking on another computer under "Network" in Windows Explorer, it says "This folder is empty." The other computer's sharing settings are set to share it's files on this network, and it can access my files just fine. Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Often I've found that making a shortcut to a network resource using UNC notation works even though that resource cannot be opened through Windows Explorer. E.G. *\\ComputerName*  or *\\ComputerName\SharedFolderName*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik How do you share specific folders?

Comment: Why not search the web for that?